# Arguments to Python Function

Tags: python, bash, shell

Function in bash looks like:

```
send_log() {
    python3 -c 'from support.config import *, send_log($?)'
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, `send_log($?)` is just to get an idea of problem statement.

I want to pass an argument to a python function, from shell script.
I can do it by using the If statement, but need an optimal way of handling this situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can do it by using the If statement"? Could you show some code for this?

Comment: Its just usecase specific, when its exit 0, I can call function with hard coded argument. when its not i can do something else. I am looking for generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, this is the simplest way:

```
send_log() {
    python3 -c 'from support.config import *; send_log("'$1'")'
}
```

In this way the parameter to python3 (ie. the Python script) is constructed dynamically, by concatenating `from support.config import *; send_log("`, your parameter `$1` and `")` to close the function call.

**Update:** Another way is to use `sys.argv`:

```
send_log() {
    python3 -c 'from support.config import *; from sys import argv;  send_log(argv[1])' $1
}
```

which has the benefit of being protected against attack mentioned by @Poshi.

Comment: Beware of code injection, if you go through this path. Make sure the input is sanitized or from a trusted source.

Comment: @Poshi : The OP wanted to interpolate `$?`, so in his case, there is no risk of code injection.

Comment: @user1934428 that was not clear to me. OP said that was only to get an idea, so I was not sure what he really wanted to pass. In fact, the proposed and accepted solution is not using `$?` but `$1`.

Comment: @Poshi : Yes, this puzzled me too. I was surprised anyway that the OP wanted to pass the exit code of the most-recent command to his `send_log`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the signature of the Python function `send_log`, which you are attempting to call here, but assuming that it accepts an integer as parameter (because, after all, you are trying to pass to it an integer value in your example), you could invoke it as

```
 python3 -c "from support.config import *, send_log($?)"
```

The double quotes ensure that bash replaces `$?` by the current status code. Of course if you are going to pass through more general arguments (i.e. strings), you have to do it either via `sys.argv`, as Błotosmętek suggested in his answer, or via an environment variable:

```
LOG_ARG="whatever you want to pass" python3 -c 'from support.config import *; import os; send_log(os.environ("LOG_ARG")'
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the interpolation property of single quotes and double-quotes. It's much clear now.